# python pandas dataframe change NaN to zeroes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe that has NaN values in it. Is there an easy to way to change all the NaNs to 0s? I don't want any other values to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `fillna` function within pandas:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna

```
 In [10]: df
 Out [10]:
         one       two 
 a  2.472772  1.135219 
 b       NaN       NaN 
 c  0.863937  1.224622 
 d       NaN  0.012517 

 In [11]: df2 = df.fillna(0)

 In [12]: df2 
 Out [12]: 
         one       two 
 a  2.472772  1.135219 
 b  0.000000  0.000000 
 c  0.863937  1.224622 
 d  0.000000  0.012517
```